# How to rename (refactor) a c macro in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, code-composer

I'm using Code Composer Studio which is based on eclipse Indigo. My Programm is written in C. I want to rename some macros via context-menu-->refactor-->rename. It is possible to get into "refactor mode" but eclipse refuses to do the refactoring after I press return (the macro name is changed to the old value). Is there a possibility to use the "refactor mode" anyway?

[image: Refactor mode]

Comment: You could use an editor (like `emacs`), or `ed` or `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the `rename dialog` by typing `Alt+Shift+R` twice. See whether it works.
2. Use `SourceInsight` smart rename function.
3. As Basile mentioned, use text editor like Emacas and Vi.